# What is the function of the と particle in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particle-と

The text on which I found the following sentence is here: http://watanoc.com/post-1608-gozira
So... There's a part where it says:
『すごく面白い』とネットで評判です
So my question is what does the と particle do in this sentence? And also why "すごく面白い" is between these symbols "『    』"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as Micah has said, this `と` is indeed the quoting particle.

That said, Japanese is a lot more flexible with the grammatical concept of quotation and how it fits into sentences than English is. Quotes can attach to things that you wouldn't expect them to in English - like in this case, the noun `評判`.

If you look [here](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%A8%E8%A9%95%E5%88%A4) (and ignore all the examples involving `名声と評判` because that's the exhaustive listing `と`), you can see that `~と評判` is a construction roughly meaning "have a reputation for". [Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%A9%95%E5%88%A4)'s second example sentence is in much the same vein.

In short, this comes out to something like:

> It has a reputation online for being super interesting/funny

Or more in more colloquial English:

> Everyone online says it's super interesting/funny

The quotation marks (『 』) are simply there to disambiguate the fact that quotation is going on; the phrase would be comprehensible (but perhaps not as immediately obvious to learners of the language) without them.

Comment: I thought that the meaning of the と particle was "and" something like "it is very interesting and has a reputation on the internet" but I never thought that the と particle was doing its function of quoting, anyway thanks a lot, I appreciate your input

Answer (score 0):

According to [https://jisho.org/word/と](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%A8):

> と can be a particle used for quoting (with speech, thoughts, etc.)

Concerning 『 』, according to https://www.japanesewithanime.com/2017/05/quotation-marks-japanese.html:

> There is no difference between how 「」 and 『』 affect a phrase. They are both just quotation marks and don't impact the grammar, add nuance, or whatever. There is as much difference between them as there is difference between ' and ".

**EDITED**
I could not find the phrase on the page you linked, but @DariusJahandarie pointed out it's actually on the page without kanji, with regular quotes 「」, and with extra whitespace.

> 「すごく　おもしろい」と　ネットで　ひょうばんです。

I've also removed my incorrect translation, please see the answer by @Mindful

Comment: It is on the linked page, just in kana. Also that’s not what it means.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Thanks for alerting me to the incorrect translation and showing it is the right linked page. I originally searched the page for `』` and a couple word combinations including the kanji, but never for the plain kana. I've updated my answer.